# The label indicating a shared field no longer displays for Non-Admins

Tags: content-editor

We recently upgraded to 8.2 from 7.2.

After the upgrade, the label that indicates a field is shared does not show up for non-admin users.

Is there a way to enable this label again?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue lately. It seems Sitecore 8.2 (which is the version that had this issue for me too) hides the Shared label by default for non-Admin using the following setting. All you need to do is change its value to true:

```
<setting name="ContentEditor.ShowFieldSharingLabels" value="true"/>
```

Note: I checked several Sitecore instances with different versions, they all seem to have it false by default